# Is there an efficient way to calculate rolling deviation from mean?

Tags: r, lapply, moving-average

I'd like to calculate the mean deviation '1/n[sum(Xi-mu)]' with rolling window. The 'mu' is rolling average. And Xi is rolling observation, too. Here is my sample code with window size n=10:

```
library(TTR)
dt<-rnorm(10000)
avg<-runMean(dt,n=10,cumulative=F)
df<-data.frame(dt,avg)

ls<-lapply(10:nrow(df),function(.){
    dev<-(df[(.-10+1):.,'dt']-df[.,'avg'])
    sk=mean(dev)
})

(p<-unlist(ls))
```

It seems the lapply is not an efficient way. Not sure what is alternative solution. Thank you anyone for any suggestion.

Comment: Take the mean of `abs(Xi-mu)`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this (although the differences cancel out as simply explained [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html))?

```
library(zoo)
dt <- rnorm(1000)
rollapply(dt, 10, function(x) mean(x - mean(x)))
```

Comment: It is not the variance. It the mean(Xi-mu). Variance is the mean((Xi-mu)^2)

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense, the deviations will cancel out and result in 0

Comment: You can prove it modifying the function to: `function(x) mean(x - mean(x))`

Comment: Because it will be not be zero, but it is close. It will be used to calculate skewness.

Comment: it looks good. 50% faster than mine. Hopefully there is sth much more faster.

Comment: Variance is sum of squared deviations so all terms are non-zero and they" don't cancel out." If dealing with a MAD analysis, you use `abs`,

Comment: If they are not squared they do